# SwiftUI Apple Pay Button

Tags: ios, iphone, swiftui, applepay

I created this SwiftUI Apple Pay Button, it works in SwiftUI projects and it works in projects created using UIKit.  The issue is when I attempt to use the ApplePayButtonRepresentable code in my work UIKit project, the ApplePayButtonRepresentable code does not compile, although it compiles and works if I create a blank project from scratch.

The errors I get include the following:

**Type 'ApplePayButton.ApplePayButtonRepresentable' does not conform to protocol 'UIViewRepresentable'**

I have tried to use type alias, but I still get the errors

**Value of type 'Context' has no member 'coordinator'**

Does anyone know of a solution?

Thanks

```
 extension ApplePayButton {
    struct ApplePayButtonRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
        var action: () -> Void
        
        func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
            context.coordinator.button
        }
        
        func updateUIView(_ rootView: UIView, context: Context) {
            context.coordinator.action = action
        }
        
        func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
            Coordinator(action: action)
        }
    }
    
    final class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var action: () -> Void
        var button = PKPaymentButton(paymentButtonType: .buy, paymentButtonStyle: .black)
        
        init(action: @escaping () -> Void) {
            self.action = action
            super.init()
            
            button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(callback(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        }
        
        @objc
        func callback(_ sender: Any) {
            action()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the `UIView` type in the make and update func declarations with `PKPaymentButton`

I'd recommend also making the button in the Coordinator a lazy so it gets init when make is called.

Answer (score 0):

If it works in some projects but not in others, it's more than likely that there's a naming conflict going on somewhere.

In this case, I'd suggest that the compiler is having trouble identifying which `Coordinator` you mean. It's picking a different one somewhere else in your code, and the error messages you're seeing are a consequence of it getting confused about your intentions.

In most examples of `UIViewRepresentable` code with a coordinator, the `Coordinator` class is defined *inside* the representable struct, so when you reference it in the `makeCoordinator()` method, the compiler doesn't have to look anywhere else. As you've moved your Coordinator outside the struct, you need to give a little helping hand.

You could give more namespacing assistance so that the compiler knows exactly which class to use:

```
func makeCoordinator() -> ApplePayButton.Coordinator {
  ApplePayButton.Coordinator(action: action)
}
```

Another option is to be explicit with a typealias:

```
struct ApplePayButtonRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
  typealias Coordinator = ApplePayButton.Coordinator

  func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(action: action)
  }
}
```

You could also rename the `Coordinator` to something unique, or move the definition inside the `UIViewRepresentable` block.